# Datagridview resized automatically at design time in a inherited forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance, datagridview

i have a problem with a inherited forms

i have a FormBase with some standard button like OK and CANCEL
at next level i have a FrmBase1 and there are a controls like textbox, numeric up and down, label ecc.. 
at next level i have a FrmBase2 with other controls like datagridview, link label, tab controls ecc...
and there is another level with a FrmFinal where i set the size, color and anchor of the inherited controls, write custom code ecc...

the levels are like this:

- frmBase

  - is inherited by frmBase1

    - is inherited by frmBase2

      - is inherited by frmFinal

the problem is only at design time: the datagridview in frmBase2 that is inherited by frmFinal increase its size every time i rebuild the solution. So if i have a datagridview 200x300 after first recompile, at design time, the datagridview is shown 300x400, and if i hit another time F6 and rebuild the solution the size increase at 500x700 but when i run the application the size is correct.

I wonder how to avoid this problem.

Thanks a lot

I'm using visual studio 2012 but the problem is the same from 2008 to 2013

Comment: I'd recommend to not to use inheritance with forms. Use aggregation, based on `UserControl`s instead.

Comment: unluckily it's not possible now to change, maybe for the future it's a good advice, thanks Dennis